# Update controls field when page load

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I fill some controls with data from data base, by calling a select method

and I change the values to update it, but when I press update button, it takes the values that called at the page load, and ignore all changes.

how can I avoid this ?

thanks in advance : )

here is a simple code to present my problem

```
SelectBLL _selectbll;
string _title = string.Empty;
string _details = string.Empty;


#region Page Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetUMedicineDetails();
}
#endregion

#region Get UMedicine Details
private void GetUMedicineDetails()
{
    _selectbll = new SelectBLL();
    _selectbll._GetUMedicineDetails(Request.QueryString[0].ToString(), ref _title, ref _details);
    #region Bind Controls
    txtdetails.Text = _details;
    txttitle.Text = _title;
    #endregion
}
#endregion

#region Update Button
protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _UpdateUMedicine();
}
#endregion

#region UpdateU Medicine
public void _UpdateUMedicine()
{
    _updatebll = new UpdateBLL();
    _updatebll._UpdateUMedicine(
        Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[0]), txtdetails.Text, txttitle.Text);
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)**: Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetUMedicineDetails();
    }
}
```

Also, Refer:

**[How to: Determine How ASP.NET Web Pages Were Invoked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

`DataBind` only if [`!Page.IsPostaBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostaBack)
        GetUMedicineDetails();
}
```